# How Can I Add a Scrollbar (Jscrollpane) to a Fixed layout (centered 2 columns + header, 100% height) Column

Tags: jquery, css, layout, fixed

I'm trying to create a centered (margin:0 auto) 2 column layout with header that fits (100%) the screen. I need to make a separate scroll bar for each column (afterwards I want to change that scroll bar to a jscrollPane).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put your two columns/divs/ in another 'column' then center it using margin:auto. Afterwards you could use either auto or scroll value for the overflow property. Something like that:

```
<div style="margin:auto;">
   <div style="overflow:scroll" ></div>
   <div style="overflow:scroll" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

the important attributes are: `overflow` and `height`

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height:100%; }
div.scroll {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
</style>
```

I am not sure this is working in all browsers...

Comment: I need the internal column to have a fluid height - to fill the screen, I'm looking for a way to get it fit the browser screen